# Is it possible to use laptops IO port with myinternal desktop GPU (gtx 1060)

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, external-display

I would like to use my laptops monitor as an extension to my desktop PC, using the GPU inside my desktop. I dont really mind butchering the laptop if I had to disable anything. The laptop is pretty basic. It does seem to have some kind of input (its the one shaped like old Amiga joystick port, I think called RS232)

Can anyone tell me if this is possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the laptops LCD directly from the laptop.

However, it is possible to use the LCD by removing it and getting an appropriate driver board.  Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfirQC99xPc) that explains it.

Edit:  There *are* some laptops with video input, but they are *extremely* rare and expensive.  I would bet my bottom dollar you dont have one.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. No this is a basic laptop and its Dell so I doubt any of ti will work. I guess I'll have to go dig my old flatscreen monitor from about 10 years ago out from whereever I stashed it haha. cheers